# Why someone put email address as image instead text?

Tags: image, email, text, html

I noticed that most of my lecturers have their e-mail addresses put on their webpages as a image not text. I never encountered that practice on other sites. Why would someone like to put it this way? To prevent some bots from reading it? Or just to annoy students (since you can't copy paste it)?

Comment: How is this question related to programming?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd like to think it was "just to annoy students", but the truth is that it's to annoy bots.

Any text in the HTML markup is easily readable by a bot (whether it be Googlebot, or something more nefarious).

By putting it in an image, it makes sure that humans can read it but (most) bots will struggle, or simply not bother trying.

Obviously, the reason you don't want bots knowing your address is because you're then a target for spam, phishing, etc.

Comment: So as I thought. Do you ever encountered something like that before? If there is a better way to hide that email from bots? Maybe some javascript that would put email address in place after loading?

Comment: @korda Yes, I've seen it in many places and it's quite common, as is the JavaScript technique you mention. The downside of the JavaScript one, however, is that not having JS enabled can hide the address from humans as well as the bots and if not properly obfuscated, the bot could still read the plaintext if it's clever enough.

Answer (score 0):

To stop spambots from cloning them onto mailing lists usually.